# Send the value to the variable Args from C# to axapta 2012

Tags: c#, wcf, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I do wcf-service, which will work with tables in Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2012. I must use method from Ax. I use CallStaticClassMethod, where "ToroCreateLineJour" is name of table, and "main" is name of method

```
ar1 = (AxaptaRecord)axapta.CallStaticClassMethod("ToroCreateLineJour", "main", tableName);
```

i must send name of tables, where i use this method, and tablename is name of this table.
But, i don't know, how send value to parameter in method "main". This parameter has type "Args".

```
static void main(Args _args){...}
```

So, can you say or better show with example, how send value to ax-method?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *`tableName`* you have to create instance of [`Args`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/args.aspx).

```cs
var args = new Args();
args.record(tableName); // if tableName is record

// or if tableName is string
//args.parm(tableName);

ar1 = (AxaptaRecord)axapta.CallStaticClassMethod("ToroCreateLineJour", "main", args);
```

Comment: Are type Args in C# and Args in Ax the same?

Comment: AX generates proxy classes for you to expose the same types, as soon as you reference AX service in C# solution.

Comment: @Matej, i try write this code, but VS didn't understand type Args. So, this example didn't work